# JavaScript function return False and 0 respectively

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I am new to JavaScript and I am trying to write functional Programming to calculate if a number is Odd (isOdd) or not. I do not understand why I've got true and 0 or false and 1 when I called isOdd() twice in a row.

here is my code:

```
var mod = m => {return number => {return number % m }}
var eq = number1 => {return number2 => {return number1 === number2}}
var combine = (...fns) => { return arg => {for(let fn of fns.reverse()) arg = fn(arg); return arg;}}

var eq1 = eq(1)
var mod2 = mod(2)
var isOdd = combine(eq1, mod2)

mod2(4) -----> returns 0
mod2(3) -----> returns 1
eq1(1)  -----> returns true
eq1(2)  -----> returns false

isOdd(1) returns true
isOdd(1) returns 1 (what??)
```

I can not understand what I missed or what goes wrong. I tested this code in most browsers.

Appreciate if someone can explain in details.

I can wrap isOdd again and have something like

```
isOdd = (number) => {return Boolean(combine(eq1, mod2))}
```

that returns boolean value everytime. But I want to understand what I missed in the first place/

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: `Array#reverse` reverses the elements *in-place*, so each time you call a `combine`d function you're doing it in the opposite order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) reverses the `fns` array in-place. You’re calling `.reverse` on `fns` *every time* you call `isOdd`, even though you pass a fixed argument list of functions in `combine` *once*. That list is scoped to `combine` and reversed on every call of `isOdd(1)`.

In other words, your first `isOdd(1)` call remembers the `fns` array of your original `combine(eq1, mod2)` call. `fns` is `[ eq1, mod2 ]`. Then you call `fns.reverse()` to iterate over it; but this *mutates* `fns` to `[ mod2, eq1 ]`. You get the correct result, because you wanted to call the functions in reverse order. The resulting call is `eq1(mod2(1)) === eq1(1) === true`.

In your second `isOdd(1)` call, however, `fns` is *still* remembered, and it *still* has the reversed `[ mod2, eq1 ]` value, because its scope is `combine`, so another `isOdd` call doesn’t reset the originally passed `fns`. The second `isOdd` call reverses this array *again* because `fns.reverse` is called within `isOdd`. The resulting call is `mod2(eq1(1)) === mod2(true) === 1` (because `true % 2` is coerced to `1 % 2`).

A working function would look like this:

```js
const combine = (...fns) => {
    const reversedFns = fns.reverse();

    return (arg) => {
      for(let fn of reversedFns){
        arg = fn(arg);
      }
  
      return arg;
    };
  };
```

A simpler approach uses [`Array.prototype.reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight):

```js
const combine = (...fns) => (arg) => fns.reduceRight((result, fn) => fn(result), arg);
```

Since you want to aggregate multiple operations onto a single result based on a list from right to left, `reduceRight` is the perfect method for this. You start with `arg`, go through the list of functions from right to left, then call the current function with `arg`, and that becomes the new `arg` for the next function. The final result is returned. All this is captured by the code `fns.reduceRight((result, fn) => fn(result), arg)`.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your detail explanation.